# how can we say "before load() function do something"

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to get a file with the load(); function in  PHP ajax, and i want to make a spinner before the load() function get my file.
so how can i say : before the load() function get the file in my div put a spinner in this place, after the load() function get the file put this file in place of the spinner.

```
<div class="storeShowInModal"></div>
$("#myStoreId").click(function()
{
    $('.storeShowInModal').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin w3-text-blue" style="font-size:36px"></i>');
    $(".storeShowInModal").load("myStore.php");
});
```

Comment: Just write your code before the call to `load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok what about this

```js
function loadContent(){
    $(".spinner").show();
    $(".storeShowInModal").load("myStore.php",function(){
        $(".spinner").hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `load()` is a wrapper for an AJAX call you could use [`ajaxSend()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [`ajaxSuccess()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) functions to display a spinner before the load request and then remove that display once the request is successful. This all happens outside of your function and is called by jQuery's AJAX facilities.

HTML

```
<span id="loading"><img src="spinner.gif" /></span>
```

jQuery

```
$("#loading").ajaxSend(function(){
   $(this).show();
 });

$("#loading").ajaxSuccess(function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });
```

Keep in mind that this will be done for each and every AJAX request. If you want something custom to the event, you have to write and call the display from your original function.